# Parse a string from a textBox input in Visual C++

Tags: visual-c++

This is my question, how  to parse a string from a textBox input in Visual C++. I have this kind of project that my input needs to be a year. The program will give a result in a label whether it is a leap year or not. I'm good in C++/CLI but Visual is kind of different. Please really need help here.

Here is the partial code:

```
      String ^ year;
      year = textBox1->Text;

     // The code for parsing will be put here

      bool isLeapYear = ((year % 4 == 0) && (year % 100 != 0) || (year % 400 == 0));

             if (isLeapYear)
             {
                label1->Text="Is a leap year";
             } else
                label1->Text="Is not a leap year";
             }
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the .NET [System.Convert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.aspx) class to convert from one type to another.

Comment: I prefer if you could give me an example.